# Ruby on Rails - Best way to render AWS S3 images in PDF reports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application that generates a report with thumbnail images processed by carrierwave and stored in AWS S3.

I tested this report with only 20records. 
I tried  Wicked PDF and Prawn to generate this report.

However, the report is getting loaded after a lot of waiting time. I can sense this situation will deteriorate the end users experience.

Do you have any recommendation to generate these kind of reports quickly.

Thanks

Comment: There's a lot of things to breakdown here that could be the problem and tough to figure out without more specifics. Can you provide an example of the page that you're transforming to a PDF? Try to breakup the steps to see if it's the PDF generation that's the problem or if it's your page rendering. In some cases, depending on the complexity of your reports you'll want to generate them on a background job so that they don't block for users. There are other problems too generally associated with reporting, so some more code / details will go a long way.

Comment: @GavinMiller The report is just to show a list of items along with its image in a table. The HTML page shows these items in a table which is getting loaded quite fast. But it takes time to show this table in a PDF. As you have rightly pointed about background job, that seems to be the only way to make user experience smoother. I am not sure if there is any proper reporting tool in Ruby (I have already tested with Wicked PDF and Prawn ) which can fetch and render remote images faster ?